# What's the best pattern in data modeling for relating real people to app users?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, data-modeling

This is a design question.

I need to come up with a Data Model for a small app and I'm looking for the best approach.

A simplified version of the business I'm trying to model has the following entities:

- **Assignments**: These are like projects, they have a start date, end date and a team of people associated
- **Workers**: These are the people that execute assignments. A given worker can only be associated to one assignment at a time. Many workers can be associated to the same assignment at the same time (for big projects).
- **Manager**: There's basically few managers in this business, who are in charge of allocating workers into new assignments as they come.

Then, there's the Web app that the **Manager** will use to manage who does what, i.e. which worker gets assigned to which assignment. The **Workers** will also use this app to register expenses associated to their assignments.

So in the context of the Web app, there will also be the **User** entity, and both workers and the manager will have their users to access the app.

My question is:
What's the best data model to support this (simple) system?

I picture this model:

- USER (id, username, password, ...)
- PERSON (inherits from user + name, email, etc...)
- MANAGER (inherits from person + extra fields for manager only)
- WORKER (inherits from person + extra fields for worker only)

What I don't like about this model is that every person must have a user. Maybe that happens today with workers and managers, but i will then add "customers" to this system, which will also have people associated that won't access the site, so they won't have a user.

Is there a better approach? Is there a standard approach without inheritance maybe?

---

**Update**

Ok, based on the model suggested above and completing with some extra info about this particular business, here's the (basic) model.

```
PERSON
id
email
passmd5
role_id
firstname
lastname
...

ROLE
id
description

PERMISSION
id
description

ROLE_PERMISSION
role_id
permission_id

COMPANY
id
name
contact_name
contact_email

ASSIGNMENT
id
customer_company_id
start_date
end_date
location_lat
location_lng
location_description

MACHINE
id
brand
model
description

PERSON_MACHINE_EXPERTISE
person_id
machine_id
```

Here's some extra information about the business to help understand the whole diagram:

- The business consists on sending people who are experts in some kind of machinery to different locations around the world, to give service to a given customer.
- There are people who are the "experts".
- There are people who are the "managers" (probably just one, but there could be more).
- There are assignments (a job, basically, which requires expert people to complete the job, sometimes more than one expert).
- There are customers, who are basically companies, not people.
- There are machines.
- There's information about which person is an expert on which machine.

Makes sense? Any ideas that may improve this?

Answer (score 1):

To approach this problem without inheritance you could perhaps define a `Person` class and a `Role` class, with every `Person` having a list of `Role`s (or a single one based on the needs of the domain).

The Manager and Worker concepts will then fall under a `Role` class, with some people having the *Manager* role (the managers) and others the *Worker* role. This will simplify the management of all `Person` objects as modifying their status, permissions and such being reduced to updating the role in the system. It will also give you the flexibility of adding new `Role`s without having to modify the source: simple create a new instance of `Role`, say *Customer* and assign it to whoever `Person` is needed.

Lastly, you could create a another concept, call it `Permission` that defines what can a `Person` do, with *Worker* and *Manager* roles having a *CanAccessWebApp* permission (and the *Customer* not). This will offer you a lot of flexibility in the long run while keeping the overall relationship design rather simple.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the "Party-Role" pattern, pretty common for this type of problem.

Comment: I kind of like the approach. But my customers are companies, not people. So maybe I treat them separately. See a modified model below.

Comment: Model below? Where? In any case, you originally mentioned `Person`, so I assumed people. The design can be translated to handle companies, though.

Comment: I just posted the model. It took me some time, i tried to upload a picture and was unable (related to my reputation cause i'm a new user).